# How do I rearrange the order of the Mentions in a Expression in VersionOne?

Tags: java, rest, versionone

I create Conversations for VersionOne Assets programatically using the Java API. When checking the conversations on the Web UI, I see that the assets mentioned are alphabetically arranged.

I would like to know if there is a way to override the default arrangement of the mentions. The target arrangement would be from Parent Asset -> Children.

Something like this:

- Default: Add reset Button (Task), Add submit Button (Task), Create UI (Story)
- Target: Create UI (Story), Add reset Button (Task), Add submit Button (Task)

Some things I tried:

1. Looking at the Expression and Message metadata. Can't find anything related to either sorting or ordering.
2. Adding the Parent Asset 1st followed by the children:

   ```
   // create a new conversation; this will act as the container of the expression (message)

   IAssetType conversationType = super.connection.metaModel.getAssetType(CONVERSATION);
   Asset conversationAsset = super.connection.services.createNew(conversationType, Oid.Null);
   super.connection.services.save(conversationAsset);

   // create a new expression containing the error message

   IAssetType expressionType = super.connection.metaModel.getAssetType(EXPRESSION);
   IAttributeDefinition expressionContentAttr = super.connection.metaModel.getAttributeDefinition(EXPRESSION_CONTENT);
   IAttributeDefinition expressionBelongsTo = super.connection.metaModel.getAttributeDefinition(EXPRESSION_BELONGS_TO);
   IAttributeDefinition expressionMentionsAttr = super.connection.metaModel.getAttributeDefinition(EXPRESSION_MENTIONS);

   Asset expressionAsset = super.connection.services.createNew(expressionType, Oid.Null);

   // set the message
   expressionAsset.setAttributeValue(expressionContentAttr, message);

   // add the message to the conversation
   expressionAsset.setAttributeValue(expressionBelongsTo, conversationAsset.oid);

   // set the context of the expression to belong to the VersionOne record
   Oid oid = Oid.fromToken(entity.oid, super.connection.metaModel);
   expressionAsset.addAttributeValue(expressionMentionsAttr, oid);

   // add mentions of other assets to the conversation
   for (String assetOid : assetOids) {
       Oid otherOid = Oid.fromToken(assetOid, super.connection.metaModel);
       expressionAsset.addAttributeValue(expressionMentionsAttr, otherOid);
   }

   super.connection.services.save(expressionAsset);
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check meta, you’ll see that Mentions is a multi-relation attribute. Unfortunately there is no way to set the order of items in the multi-relational attribute.
Here’s the query for checking meta:

https://www14.v1host.com/v1sdktesting/meta.v1/Expression?xsl=api.xsl

The VersionOne UI has some logic that is setting the order of the Conversation mentions before displaying them.